# ¿Como crear una dll que englobe a todas las demás?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

En el momento de crear un proyecto de tipo "Biblioteca de Clases, habitualmente uno puede generar una dll al compilar. ¿Pero como podría generar una dll sin que pierda otras que ya tengo incluidas?.

Me explico con un ejemplo: Resulta que descargue de paquetes Nuget una dll S22.Imap con la trabajaba, posteriormente generaba la dll de la forma tradicional que explique en el principio, pero cuando quería trabajar con dll en otro computador, me salia errores que no encontraba funciones que contenía la dll S22.IMAP. Entonces para solucionar ese problema, tuve que copiar la dll de mi proyecto, S22.IMAP de forma adicional en una ruta especifica del otro computador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi pregunta es:**

¿Cómo se podría generar una dll que incluya las que había incluido en el proyecto con la que se trabajaba.?

Answer (score 1):

Al agregar las librerías desde Nuget, tu nueva DLL no podrá contener las DLL que hayas agregado al proyecto. Pero si puedes indicar en las referencias del proyecto, en las propiedades de la DLL, la opción ["Copy Local" = True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602765/when-should-copy-local-be-set-to-true-and-when-should-it-not). Con esto, al compilar y generar la nueva DLL, en el directorio BIN tendrás las DLL que haces referencia.

Ahora, también deberás tener en cuenta la propiedad ["Fixed path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119539/how-do-i-set-the-path-to-a-dll-file-in-visual-studio) de las referencias, para que en tus futuros proyecto, cuando agregues una de las librerías, y esta utilice a otras librerías, Visual Studio sepa de donde obtener las referencias.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Un saludo.